# Show IP route output on a single line with regex or other

Tags: cisco, router

I am scripting with Bash, and I need to be able to print route output on a single line. The issue I have is that some routing protocols print the `show ip route` & `show ip eigrp topology` & other `show ip route` output on two lines per `prefix`.

I want to know if there is any way to get it to print on the same line with a Cisco regex or other command. For example, the BGP route below prints on the same line which is what I need.

---

**NEXUS:**

Non-working example - prints info on second line:

```
router1# show ip eigrp topology all-links vrf X | section 172.19.32.0/20
 P 172.19.32.0/20, 1 successors, FD is 1563136, serno 6042
    via 172.19.47.3 (1563136/1562880), Vlan320, serno 6035 !prints the rest of output on second line.
```

---

**Cisco Routers:**

Working example:

```
router#show ip route vrf x | i 172.19.0.0/20
B        172.19.0.0/20 [20/0] via 172.19.15.250, 1w3d !BGP is great it shows up on one line.
```

Non-working example - prints info on second line:

```
router#show ip route vrf x | i 172.19.32.0/20
D EX     172.19.32.0/20 
       [170/3328] via 172.19.15.42, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/0/1 !EIGRP routes suck because it shows the rest of the output on the second line.
```

---

This becomes important with the grep statements I need to do in bash for example:

Working example: prints on same line - this can get us what we need.

```
user@host:~$ ssh router "show ip route vrf x" | grep 172.19.0.0/20
B        172.19.0.0/20 [20/0] via 172.19.15.250, 1w3d
```

Non-working example: cant' get the second line of output.

```
user@host:~$ ssh router "show ip route vrf x" | grep 172.19.32.0/20
D EX     172.19.32.0/20
```

So, I am just trying to see if anyone knows of a way in Cisco commands or otherwise to get the second line of `show ip route` & `show ip eigrp topology` or other `show ip route` commands.

Comment: I found something that does the trick but still interested if there is any comments. user@host$ ssh router "show ip route vrf x" | grep -A 1 172.19.32.0/20 | sed -e '1d' ====== output ===== [170/3328] via 172.19.15.42, 7w0d, GigabitEthernet0/0/1

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have very mixed success with the different Cisco OSes, and different versions (IOS, IOS-XE, NX-OS, etc.) and how things are presented.

For IOS, the `show ip rib route` command shows what's in the RIB like `show ip route`, and I suppose it depends on the IOS version, but I see `show ip rib route` output on single lines where `show ip route` shows output on two lines.

The `show ip cef` command shows what's in the FIB, in a very compressed format, just:

```
 Prefix     Next Hop     Interface
```